# Python game of life generates wrong structures

Tags: python, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to program [the game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) in python. I keep getting the wrong structure generated after generation and pinpointed my mistake to the fuction bellow.

**What I want the program to do:**

It should iterate through an array to determine if the cell is going to be alive or dead in next generation and places them in an array "cells"
INPUT: (.-dead cell x- Alive cell)

...

xxx

...

OUTPUT

.x.

.x.

.x.

**What is happening now:**
The program iterates through cells and changes them. Then it uses the new values instead of the original ones to determine if the next cell is alive.

INPUT:

...

xxx

...

OUTPUT

.xx

x.x

...

**Additional info:**

Both arrays have a frame of permanently dead cells around.

```
    def nextGen(matrice):
cells = matrice
size = np.shape(matrice)
for i in range(1,size[0]-1):
    for j in range(1,size[1]-1):
        if matrice[i][j] > 0:
            alive = True
        else:
            alive = False    
        neighbours = 0    
        neighbours += matrice[i-1,j+1]
        neighbours += matrice[i-1,j] 
        neighbours += matrice[i-1,j -1]
        neighbours += matrice[i,j+1] 
        neighbours += matrice[i,j -1]
        neighbours += matrice[i+1,j+1]
        neighbours += matrice[i+1,j] 
        neighbours += matrice[i+1,j -1]
        if alive:
            if neighbours != 2 and neighbours !=3:
                cells[i,j] = 0
                #print("Cell has died", i, j, "Neighbours: ", neighbours)
        else:
            if neighbours == 3:
                cells[i,j] = 1
                #print("Cell was born", i, j,"Neighbours: ", neighbours)                    
        neighbours = 0
return cells
```

Comment: `cells = matrice` doesn't make a copy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was as @user2357112 suggested that `cells = matrice` doesn't make a copy.
To fix that I needed to change it to `cells = np.copy(matrice)` .